# Self-host a Django Website

Tags: django, python-3.x, self-hosting

Is it possible to host a website built with Django on one's personal machine? If so, how?

I built a small Django site, my first, based on a tutorial, and I want to make it live, so that I can see how it looks on other computers/devices, and allow friends/family to check it out. I have no way of purchasing a server.

Comment: Possible?  Yes.  Practical?  No.

Comment: I think this is probably too broad _in general_, but it's certainly too broad as written. What is the site for? You want a site that only you will use, doesn't have to be secure, and can only be accessed from your home LAN? Sure, go right ahead. Building the next amazon.com? Certainly not.

Comment: I just want to view my website from say, the library, or my phone at the local Dunkin Donuts. Nothing fancy. I just want a way for friends/family/me to see the webstie without using my machine.

Comment: Put it on Docker or Heroku using a free account. You could do this using dynamic DNS and other such things but unless you really know what you're doing it's not worth the added security risk to your home network.

Comment: What can be done to add security to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to do what you're asking for is by using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) on your machine (using homebrew on a mac, `brew install ngrok`)

You would need to sign up at https://ngrok.com/signup to get an authtoken to password protect your site.

Install the authtoken: `ngrok authtoken your_authtoken_here`

To run your django app in your terminal, you would run (note that you could specify a different port; Django runs on 8000 by default):

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And then in another terminal window you would run:

```
ngrok http -auth='username:password' 8000
```

You'll see a screen with a line that looks like this:

```
Forwarding                    http://sfd98sdf.ngrok.io -> localhost:8000
```

You can then visit `http://sfd98sdf.ngrok.io` to view your site.

You would have to keep your machine running these processes for this to work.

Note that as commenters have said, this isn't the best or most secure way, but it's a quick way to do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: The  [cloudflare warp](https://warp.cloudflare.com/) also seems  worth a shot. The concept is  similar